# Implementation of a Data-Structure supporting various operations

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I have to implement a data structure which supports the following three functions. The data is a pair(a,b) of two double values and the data is concentrated in a particular region. Let's say with values of 'a' in the range 500-600.

1. Insert(double a, double b) - Insert the data, a pair(double,double) in the data structure. If the first element of the pair already exists, update its second element to the new value.
2. Delete(double a) - Delete the data containing the first element = a.
3. PrintData(int count) - Print the value of the data which has the count-th largest value. Value is compared according to data.first.

The input file contains a series of Insert, Delete and PrintData operations. Currently, I have implemented the data structure as a height balanced binary search tree using STL-Map but it is not fast enough.

Is there any other implementation which is faster than a Map. 
We can use caching to store the most common PrintData queries.

Comment: @Inertiatic A priority queue won't (efficiently) support a "count-th largest value" query, as per #3.

Comment: @Dukeling I must have misunderstood the question. Edit: You're right, I see where I strayed off. Delete has to search and delete that element, which can be anywhere in the data structure.

Comment: How any elements are in the data structure? Unless there are many thousands it is likely that using an ordered vector of the key and a parallel vector with the values and inserting/deleting into these is a lot faster! If you can reasonably bucket the elements, e.g., using a conversion to `int` and then searching within a vector you could expand the data structure efficiently to a lot more elements. When updating a value you'd also immediately store the current maximum value/count if the count is bigger than the current one (no need to go searching for that).

Comment: The parameter 'a' is used for ordering(comparison between two data values). But, we need to print the count-th largest value,not the highest value.

Comment: @DietmarKühl There are approximately 6,00,000 elements in the data structure finally.

Comment: Oh, I see: the second value need to be maintained, too! So, to deal with the second value you'll, indeed, use a priority queue: the first map points to the current element in the [adjustable] priority queue and the key gets changed upon update (insertion just stores a handle to the element in the priority queue). I'd still based this entirley only arrays although d-heaps are not ideal for being modifyable...

Comment: OK. See to cluster the data suitably to use have each vector have at most ~10000 elements. Or you code use a b-tree (note the "b" does _not_ stand for "binary"!) and get most of the benefits of locality. Each leaf-node would still point to an element in a priority queue use to adjust the node as necessary to efficiently report the current largest value.

Comment: ... and looking at the requirement to find the n-th largest element efficiently, a priority queue actually doesn't work too well: so, you'd probably use an [ordered] vector for the ordered largest elements, too: the start vector would point to the position of the current value to get it adjusted upon update.

Comment: Is this problem from any online judge. If it is, then better provide a link of that.

Comment: @Shashwat No, it isn't.

Comment: Ahm, double values are not exact. How would you look up a pair by `a`? Do we look for a pair with `a` in the range `(a' - eps, a' + eps)`? Because your compiler is free to mangle your variables so you might lose exact equality if you pass a double around.

Comment: @Niklas Sorry, I forgot to mention that all double values are mutiples    
of 0.50.

Comment: @Hellboy: Then please don't use doubles. Instead represent the pairs as a pair of integers `(a*2, b*2)`

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend 2 binary search trees (BSTs) - one being the map from `a` to `b` (sorted by `a`), the other should be sorted by `b`.

The second will need to be a custom BST - you'll need to let each node store a count of the number of nodes in the subtree with it as root - these counts can be updated in O(log n), and will allow for O(log n) queries to get the k-th largest element.

When doing an insert, you'll simply look up b's value in the first BST first, then remove that value from the second, then update the first and insert the new value into the second.

For a delete, you'll simply look up b's value in the first BST (and remove that pair), then remove that value from the second.

All mentioned operations should take O(log n).

**Caching**

If you are, for instance, only going to query the top 10 elements, you could maintain another BST containing only those 10 elements (or even just an optionally-sorted array, since there's only 10 elements), which we'll then query instead of the second BST above.

When inserting, also insert into this structure if the value is greater than the smallest one, and remove the smallest.

When removing, we need to look up the next largest value and insert it into the small BST. Although this could also be done lazily - when removing, just remove it from this BST - don't fill it up to 10 again. When querying, if there are enough elements in this BST, we can just look up using this one, otherwise we find all the values in the big BST required to fill this BST up, then we query.

This would result in best-case O(1) query (worst-case O(log n)), while the other operations will still be O(log n).

Although the added complexity is probably not worth it - O(log n) is pretty fast, even for a large n.

Building on this idea, we could *only* have this small BST along with the BST mapping `a` to `b` - this would require that we check all values to find the required ones during a query after a removal, so it would only really be beneficial if there aren't a whole lot of removals.

Comment: How can we use Caching for the third operation,given that the PrintData function takes parameter in the range 1-10 only.

Comment: If we don't consider caching, why should the second (custom) BST be sorted by "b" value as the ordering of the data is done by the "a" value. Also, the insertion is done according to the "a" value.

Even after caching, I don't think it is fast enough. I need to reduce the number of CPU cycles taken for all the operations.

Comment: @Hellboy: You just need a single search tree ordered by a. There's several high-performance data structures available for the job, for example B-trees.

Comment: @Hellboy If you're looking for the k-th largest `b` value (or did I misunderstand that part?), a single BST ordered by `a` would require that you search through all the data to find it, as it's not ordered by `b`. So that's O(n) vs O(log n) - quite a difference.

Comment: @Dukeling We have to find the k-th largest 'a' value, not 'b'.

Even after creating a small BST of size 10, we have to iterate over all the elements in the worst case in the small BST because we can't do iterator = iterator + count for Maps in C++. Therefore, what's the need for this second BST of size 10 because this iteration could have been done on the primary BST using reverse_iterator.

Comment: @Hellboy: Don't save the top-10 in the "big" BST. Just save them in a separate array. Since 10 is such a small constant, it's more or less negligible to maintain the array and to search via brute-force in it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend an [indexed skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist). That will give you O(log n) insert and delete, and O(log n) access to the nth largest value (assuming that you maintain the list in descending order).

Skip list isn't any more difficult to implement than a self-balancing binary tree, and gives much better performance in some situations. Well worth considering.

The [original skip list paper](ftp://ftp.cs.umd.edu/pub/skipLists/skiplists.pdf).

Comment: But the worst case insertion/deletion/search time complexity in skip list is O(n)

Comment: @Hellboy: Yes, worst case is O(n). The paper states that the worst case is nearly impossible to encounter. My experience bears that out. I've used skip lists a lot and have *never* run into anything even approaching that pathological behavior. I'm not saying that it can't happen, just that it's highly unlikely.